# count of non null column values with range() pandas

Tags: python, pandas, range, cumsum

I have dataframe like:

```
id     date     sum
a    1/1/2001  
a    1/1/2001
a    1/1/2001
a    1/1/2001    50
a    1/1/2001    10
a    1/1/2001    60
b    1/1/2001
b    1/1/2001
b    1/1/2001    100
b    1/1/2001    100
b    1/1/2001    
b    1/1/2001    100
```

I want a new column named Rolling which will be cumsum/cumcount but problem is cumsum is not adding null values as its empty but denominator count is taking the null values also.My code is

```
df['Rolling'] = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x['sum'].cumsum()/ range(1,len(x)+1))).values
```

I want my output as:

```
id     date     sum  Rolling
a    1/1/2001  
a    1/1/2001
a    1/1/2001
a    1/1/2001    50    50  #50/1
a    1/1/2001    10    30  #50+10/2
a    1/1/2001    60    40  #50+10+60/3
b    1/1/2001
b    1/1/2001
b    1/1/2001    100  100  #100/1
b    1/1/2001    100  100  #100+100/2
b    1/1/2001    
b    1/1/2001    100  100    #300/3
```

but instead i am getting:

```
id     date     sum  Rolling
a    1/1/2001  
a    1/1/2001
a    1/1/2001
a    1/1/2001    50    12.5  #50/4
a    1/1/2001    10    12    #50+10/5
a    1/1/2001    60    20  #50+10+60/6
b    1/1/2001
b    1/1/2001
b    1/1/2001    100  33.33 #100/3
b    1/1/2001    100  50    #200/4
b    1/1/2001    
b    1/1/2001    100  50    #300/6
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try to fix your code

```
df['mean'] = df.groupby('id')['sum'].apply(
             lambda s: s.cumsum() / s.notna().cumsum())
```

**Alternative approach**: `Group` the dataframe by `id` then calculate the `expanding` `mean` on the `sum` column. The `mean` operation by default excludes the `Null` values so we don't have to worry about keeping the track of non-Null values

```
df['mean'] = df.groupby('id').expanding()['sum'].mean().droplevel(0)
df['mean'] = df['mean'].mask(df['sum'].isna())
```

---

```
   id      date    sum   mean
0   a  1/1/2001    NaN    NaN
1   a  1/1/2001    NaN    NaN
2   a  1/1/2001    NaN    NaN
3   a  1/1/2001   50.0   50.0
4   a  1/1/2001   10.0   30.0
5   a  1/1/2001   60.0   40.0
6   b  1/1/2001    NaN    NaN
7   b  1/1/2001    NaN    NaN
8   b  1/1/2001  100.0  100.0
9   b  1/1/2001  100.0  100.0
10  b  1/1/2001    NaN    NaN
11  b  1/1/2001  100.0  100.0
```